# Nginx connect() to unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket failed

Tags: sockets, unix, nginx, gitweb

I'm trying to install Gitweb on my Nginx server.  Everything seems to be configured correctly, but I seem to be getting the following error in the gitweb.log:

```
`2015/06/08 08:42:05 [crit] 29135#0: *5 connect() to unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 83.36.85.6, server: git.mydomain.co.uk, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket:", host: "git.mydomain.co.uk"`
```

I've checked the owner/permissions and all seems to be fine.

`srwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 0 Jun  8 08:44 /var/run/fcgiwrap.socket`

The output of `ps aux | grep nginx` is:

```
root     30283  0.0  0.0  90552  1296 ?        Ss   08:59   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
forge    30284  0.0  0.0  90884  1924 ?        S    08:59   0:00 nginx: worker process                           
forge    30285  0.0  0.1  90884  2408 ?        S    08:59   0:00 nginx: worker process                           
root     30528  0.0  0.0  11980   928 pts/0    R+   09:03   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: What user nginx uses? Is it `www-data` too?

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: 30283 nginx           root     root
30284 nginx           forge    sudo,www-data,forge
30285 nginx           forge    sudo,www-data,forge

Comment: In nginx's config. It's usually first line. Or with `ps aux | grep nginx`

Comment: Thanks, I just posted the output above.

Comment: So your nginx works as `forge` user, that has no write access to `/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket`. Either change nginx's user or access to socket

Comment: Do I need to `chgrp` and `chown` `/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket` to `forge` user

Comment: The socket has to be writable for both the client and the server. Under the assumption that the server is `www-data` and the client is `forge` with group `forge`, `chgrp forge /var/run/fcgiwrap.socket` followed by `chmod g+w /var/run/fcgiwrap.socket` should allow the client to write to it.

Comment: @alvits, post your comments as an answer, get some credits :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The socket has to be readable and writable by both client and server. Under the assumption that the server is running as `www-data` and the client is running as `forge` with group `forge`, the following steps should fix the issue.

Change the group ownership of the socket to the group of user `forge`.

```
chgrp forge /var/run/fcgiwrap.socket
```

Change the group permission to allow write for group `forge`.

```
chmod g+w /var/run/fcgiwrap.socket
```

The socket will now be readable and writable by both server and client.